# Append data-slb-group=“slb”

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho varias imagens e estou tentando usar o `AppendTo` do jquery, mas não estou conseguindo

```
<a href="image1.jpg" data-slb-active="1" data-slb-asset="1947037253" data-slb-internal="0" 
data-slb-group="slb">
            <img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-527" src="image1.jpg" alt="" 
            width="300" height="225" srcset="image1.jpg" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 
           300px">
        </a>   
        <a href="image2.jpg" data-slb-active="1" data-slb-asset="1947037253" 
data-slb-internal="0" data-slb-group="slb">
            <img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-527" src="image2.jpg" alt="" 
            width="300" height="225" srcset="image2.jpg" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 
           300px">
        </a>
        <a href="image3.jpg" data-slb-active="1" data-slb-asset="1947037253"
 data-slb-internal="0" data-slb-group="slb">
            <img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-527" src="image3.jpg" alt="" 
            width="300" height="225" srcset="image3.jpg" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 
           300px">
        </a>

    <div class="images"></div>
```

o codigo abaixo funciona

```
$('.size-medium').appendTo('.images');
```

Mas vai para a  `<div class="images"></div>` todas imagens com a classe `.size-medium`, sem os links `<a>`

Eu tentei de diversas formas mas ainda não consegui:

```
$('a data-slb-group').appendTo('.images');
```

Agradeço ajuda

Comment: Queres colocar esses `<a>` e `<img>` dentro de `.images`, é isso?

Comment: Sim, é isso mesmo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma vez que as imagens estão dentro de `<a>` podes usar o seletor `a[data-slb-active]` e depois `.appendTo('.images');` assim:

```js
$('a[data-slb-active]').appendTo('.images');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="image1.jpg" data-slb-active="1" data-slb-asset="1947037253" data-slb-internal="0" data-slb-group="slb">
  <img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-527" src="image1.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="225" srcset="image1.jpg" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 
           300px">
</a>
<a href="image2.jpg" data-slb-active="1" data-slb-asset="1947037253" data-slb-internal="0" data-slb-group="slb">
  <img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-527" src="image2.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="225" srcset="image2.jpg" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 
           300px">
</a>
<a href="image3.jpg" data-slb-active="1" data-slb-asset="1947037253" data-slb-internal="0" data-slb-group="slb">
  <img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-527" src="image3.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="225" srcset="image3.jpg" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 
           300px">
</a>

<div class="images"></div>
```

Que vai dar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]